# Collection class of specific type containing basic features

Tags: vb.net

Every time i use some class e.g Artikel as follows:

```
Public Class Artikel  
   Property ID As Integer
   Property Nummer As String
   Property Name As String 
   Property Position As Integer
End Class
```

For such classes i would like to have collection class. The features i would like to have is like:

```
--> Add (passing Artikel object)
--> Remove (passing Artikel object)
--> Sort entire collection (based on Position property desc/asc)
--> Compare two Artikels (pass by Artikels and tell by which property has to be compared)
--> Check whether two artikels equals
--> Every added artikel has to be marked by Key (so maybe dictionary)? <key><Artikel>
--> Remove Artikel (passing by Key index)
```

Could somone from you there tell me or even better provide example of collection class pass those requirments?

**EDIT: Startup:**

Artikel's collection:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Articles

Public Property collection As Dictionary(Of Integer, Artikel)

Sub New()
    'Initiate new collection
    collection = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Artikel)
End Sub

   'Add new Artikel to collection
    Public Function AddToCollection(ByVal artikel As Artikel) As Boolean
        collection.Add(artikel)
        Return True
    End Function

    'Remove specific Artikel
    Public Sub RemoveFromCollectionByArtikel(artikel As Artikel)
        If Not IsNothing(collection) Then
            collection.Remove(artikel)
        End If
    End Sub

   'Get collection
   Public Function GetCollection() As Dictionary(Of Integer, Artikel)
        Return collection
    End Function

   'Sort collection by property position
   Public Sub SortByPosition()
        collection.Sort()
    End Sub

    'Remove specific sending keys and then reorder them
    Public Sub RemoveAllMarkedAsDeleted(keys As List(Of Integer))
        '-- Check whther anything has been marked as deleted
        If keys.Count > 0 Then
            For Each row In keys
                collection.Remove(row)
            Next
            ReorderKeys()
    End If

    'Reorder all Artikels in collection
    Private Sub ReorderKeys()
        Dim newCollection As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Artikel)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        For Each collitem In collection
            newCollection.Add(index, collitem.Value)
            index += 1
        Next
        collection.Clear()
        collection = newCollection
    End Sub


End Class
```

Artikel class (additionally i implemented IComparable to be able to sort)

```
Option Strict On
     Public Class Artikel   
         Implements IComparable(Of Artikel)
           Property ID As Integer
           Property Nummer As String
           Property Name As String 
           Property Position As Integer

        Public Function CompareTo(pother As Artikel) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Artikel).CompareTo    'we can sort because of this
            Return String.Compare(Me.Position, pother.Position)
        End Function
        Public Shared Function FindPredicate(ByVal partikel As Artikel) As Predicate(Of Artikel)
            Return Function(partikel2 As Artikel) partikel.ID = partikel2.ID
        End Function
        Public Shared Function FindPredicateByUserId(ByVal partikel As String) As Predicate(Of Artikel)
            Return Function(partikel2 As Artikel) partikel = partikel2.ID
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: A Dictionary will be at odds with Sorting, but if you write a collection class you can have methods to convert and return a new collection based on whatever.  Comparison would be better implemented on the Artikel class

Comment: so you mean to add method which could use current collection within collection class and sort it by my own? By the way is there possibility to get some sample from you as an answer?

Comment: You basically have 7 questions there: how do I do each of these in a collection class which makes it a bit broad and a little vague (what is this *key* that popped up?).  Start an `Artikels` class which uses a private collection internally and then ask individual questions when you get stuck.

Comment: ok just tell me the collection class should inherit from Dictionary of integer, Article? or just add property list of dictionary integer, artikel? You said internall colelction but why not inherit from dictionary what is the diffrence? Is this because i have to write additional features by my own or?

Comment: It need not inherit from anything, if it implements a collection internally.  if you inherit, all the functionality you dont override gets exposed to the consumer code.

Comment: ok will prepare something and comes back if need

Comment: @Plutonix i took some time and that's what i come with - please check - is it ok, is there something wrong or could be done better?

Comment: Turn on option strict; this will not compile: `String.Compare(Me.Position, pother.Position)`  you dont use String.Compare for an integer.  a) ask yourself if you really need `IComparable`.  b) I would not get hung up on the Dictionary aspect.  The collection class can enforce unique keys (whatever they are) without the drawbacks of a dictionary.  c)  for instance, you cannot `RemoveByIndex` the order of dictionary items is not defined/  d) Look at implementing ICollection(of Article) - it will give you good semantics for the basic ops, leaving you to decide *what* happens for each.

Comment: @Plutonix i changed a bit collection class - could you be so kind and help me with fix of Position sorting and the staff already implemented as an answer to be sure everything is correct? I think also for other people would be good start to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts of it look good, but I would ultimately do it a bit differently.  First, consider overloads on the item class to make them easier to create and default initialization:

```
Public Class Article
    Property ID As Integer = -1
    Property Key As String = ""
    Property Name As String = ""
    Property Position As Integer = -1
    Property PubDate As DateTime = DateTime.Minimum

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    ' whatever minimum data a new item requires
    Public Sub New(k As String, n As String)
        Key = k
        Name = n
    End Sub
    ' full initialization:
    Public Sub New(k As String, n As String, pos As Int32,
                    pubDt As DateTime)
       ...
   End Sub
End Class
```

I added some properties for variety, and I suspect "Nummer" might be the "Key" mentioned in the OP, but whatever it is, I would add it to the `Article` class *as that name*, if it has some importance.

You might need a simple ctor for serialization (???). Some of these will find and use a `Private` parameterless constructor, but your code will be forced to use one of the overloads in order to provide some minimum level of data when a new one is created.

---

You probably do not need `IComparable`.  That is typically for more complex comparisons, such as multiple or complex properties.  An example is a carton or box:

```
If (width = Other.Width) AndAlso (height = Other.Height) Then
    Return 0
ElseIf (width = Other.Height) AndAlso (height = Other.Width) Then
    Return 0
End If
```

Plus more gyrations to work out which is "less" than the other.  One reason you dont need it, is because `If Art1.Postion > Art2.Postion` is trivial.  The other reason in *your* case, is because a `Dictionary` cannot be sorted.

Rather than a `Dictionary`, an internal List would work better for some of the things you describe but still allow you to have it *act like* a `Dictionary` to the extent you need it to.  For this, I might build it using `ICollection<T>`:

```
Public Class ArticleCollection
    Implements ICollection(Of Article)
```

Pressing Enter after that line will add all the required methods including:

```
Public Sub Add(item As Article) Implements ICollection(Of Article).Add

Public Sub Clear() Implements ICollection(Of Article).Clear

Public Function Contains(item As Article) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of Article).Contains

Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection(Of Article).Count

Public Function Remove(item As Article) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of Article).Remove
```

It remains completely up to you *how* these are implemented. It also doesn't rule out adding methods such as `RemoveAt(int32)` or `RemoveByKey(string)` depending on what you need/how it will be used.   One of the benefits to `ICollection(Of T)` is that it includes `IEnumerable` which will allow use for each loops (once you write the Enumerator): `For Each art In Articles`

To emulate a dictionary to allow only one item with a specific property value:

```
Public Class ArticleCollection
    Implements ICollection(Of Article)

    Private mcol As List(Of Article)
    ...
    Public Sub Add(item As Article) Implements ICollection(Of Article).Add
        ' check for existing key
        If KeyExists(item.Key) = False Then
            mcol.Add(item)
        End If
    End Sub
```

You can also overload them:

```
' overload to match Article ctor overload
Public Sub Add(key As String, name As String)
     If KeyExists(key) = False Then
        ' let collection create the new item
        ' with the minimum required info
        mcol.Add(New Article(key, name))
    End If
End Sub
```

If you add an `Item` Property, you can index the collection ( `Articles(3)` ):

```
Property Item(ndx As Int32) As Article
    Get
        If ndx > 0 AndAlso ndx < mcol.Count Then
            Return mcol(ndx)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Article)
        If ndx > 0 AndAlso ndx < mcol.Count Then
            mcol(ndx) = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

' overload for item by key:
Public Property Item(key As String) As Article
```

An `Add` method and an `Item` Property will be important if the collection will display in the standard NET `CollectionEditor`.

There are several ways to implement sorting.  The easiest is to use linq in the code which uses your collection:

```
Articles = New ArticleCollection
' add Article items
Dim ArticlesByDate = Articles.OrderBy(Function(s) s.PubDate).ToList()
```

Where `PubDate` is one of the `Article` properties I added.  The other way to handle sorting is by the collection class returning a new collection (but it is so simple to do, there is little need for it):

```
Friend Function GetSortedList(bSortAsc As Boolean) As List(Of Article)
    If bSortAsc Then
        Return mcol.OrderBy(Function(q) q.PubDate).
                ThenBy(Function(j) j.Position).ToList()
    Else
        Return mcol.OrderByDescending(Function(q) q.PubDate).
                ThenByDescending(Function(j) j.Position).ToList()
    End If
End Function
```

Whether it implements `ICollection(Of T)`, inherits from `ICollection(Of T)` or does work off a `Dictionary` depends entirely on what this is, how it is used and whatever rules and restrictions there are (including if it will be serialized and how).  These are not things we know.

MSDN has an article on **[Guidelines for Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx)** which is **excellent**.

Answer (score 0):

Create your class

```
Public Class Artikel  
   Property ID As Integer
   Property Nummer As String
   Property Name As String 
   Property Position As Integer

   sub new (_ID as integer, _Nummer as string, _Name as string, _Position as integer)
      ID = _ID
      Nummer = _Nummer
      Name = _Name
      Position = _Position
   End Sub
End Class
```

Create another class which holds a private list and add sub routines to it

```
 Public Class ArtikelList
      Private _List as new list (of Artikel)

      Public sub remove(Key as integer)
         Dim obj as Artikel = nothing
         for each x as Artikel in _List
            if x.ID = Key then
               obj = x
               exit for
            end if
         Next
         if not isnothing(obj) then
               _List.remove(obj)
          end if
      End sub

      Sub Add(obj as Artikel)
         Dim alreadyDeclared as boolean = falsse

         for each x as Artikel in _List
            if x.ID = obj.id then
               alreadyDeclared = true
               exit for
            end if
         Next
          if not AlreadyDeclared then
               _List.add(obj)
          Else
             'Somehow inform the user of the duplication if need be.
          end if

      End sub
    End Class
```

Then use your list class.

```
dim L as new ArtikelList
L.add(new Artikel(1280, "AFKforever!", "Prof.FluffyButton", 96))
L.remove(1280)
```

I only added one sub routine as an example. I hope it helps but feel free to ask for more example routines.

This can also be done by creating a class which inherits from the list class, exposing all list class functionality but by using this method you are forced to create every subroutine that will be used. This way you only use routines that you created exclusively for the purpose Artikel objects handling.

**Check if two Artikels are equal**

```
Public Class Artikel  
       Property ID As Integer
       Property Nummer As String
       Property Name As String 
       Property Position As Integer

       sub new (_ID as integer, _Nummer as string, _Name as string, _Position as integer)
          ID = _ID
          Nummer = _Nummer
          Name = _Name
          Position = _Position
       End Sub
    End Class

Public Overrides Overloads Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean

      If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.GetType() Is obj.GetType() Then
         Return False
      else
        dim _obj as artikel = obj
        if Me.ID = _obj.ID then
           Return true
        else Return False
      End If

   End Function 


End Class
```

Use it like:

```
If x.equals(y) then
    'they have the same ID
end if
```

Comment: Hi thanks, i prefer Dictuionary more less as i can use keys - the Artikel Id is just database field and i want to use separated key (dictionary) to order/reoarder list...

Comment: Maybe the information on this page can help you to find easy ways to query whatever collection type you decide to use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384667.aspx

It's a real time saver.